# How do I implement a custom protocol in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm trying to implement a simple ZeroMQ socket server as a twisted protocol, my code is currently:

```
# Setup
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5558")
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)

# Respond to incoming messages.
while True:
    if poller.poll(1000):
        msg = self.socket.recv()
        print "Received a message ..."
    else:
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

and I found:

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IProtocol.html

but honestly can't make sense of it. Where should I be putting the code for setup, and code for receiving data?

Comment: Did you have a peek at the tutorials? https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/core/howto/servers.html

Comment: Yes I read that but can't figure out where my code goes. For example transport.write would just write to a TCP socket and I want to read/write a ZMQ socket. I feel that it doesn't allow me to access low enough in the stack.

Comment: Should I be implementing it as a transport perhaps?

Comment: I really am not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve as I am not fluent with zeroMQ. What I can suggest though is to have a look at PyZMQ or other already existing bindings for python and take your inspiration from there.

Comment: What are you trying to do?